# Redis server is running but no response from the server

Tags: node.js, redis

I am running a redis server for my project and it seems to work fine. I checked it by running the command

> redis-cli

But when I try running the following code it doesn't give me any response

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function(err){
    console.error("Errro encountered: ", err);
});

client.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Redis connected");
});
```

Can someone please help me. I am totally new into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are creating a client, you are properly installing event handlers but you forgot to actually connect to the redis server.

Using this code:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function(err){
    console.error("Errro encountered: ", err);
});

client.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Redis connected");
});

client.connect(); // connect to the server here!
```

You will get the result that you probably expected. [Basic example](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#basic-example) in the github readme of the redis node module should be a good reference for that.

**EDIT:** Apparently, the module used to automatically connect to a database during the `createClient()` call, but it does not anymore due to some [breaking changes between versions](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/v3-to-v4.md#no-auto-connect), so now an explicit `client.connect()` call is needed.

Comment: Thanks. That works